# Why is Jewelry Bonney crying after Whitebeard's death?

Tags: one-piece

I saw her crying hard after Whitebeard's death.

[image]

She even tried to avenge his death. Given the fact that she encountered Blackbeard so soon after the war, it seems likely that she has grudge on him, as he was the man responsible for Whitebeard's death.

What is her relationship to WhiteBeard?

Comment: hey, what chapter is this?

Comment: @JTR Chapter 581

Answer (score 2):

Still, it is not clear whether she is crying because of whitebeards death or Ace death.
But as per [this theory](http://opforum.net/threads/jewelry-bonneys-relation-with-ace.3762/) she is crying because of the Ace's death.
Also you can read [this.](http://www.marineford.com/Thread-One-Piece-Jewelry-Bonney-Daughter-Of-Akainu-Half-Sister-Of-Ace)

Comment: Could be true about Ace but this is about Whitebeard's death. Bonney even tried to kill Blackbeard to avenge him. So Bonney might be deeply related to WhiteBeard to do such thing.

Comment: @bot but Blackbeard is the one that give Ace to marines.

Comment: I have added few links.